# Setting max_map_count for a particular docker container debian

Tags: docker, elasticsearch, memory-management

I am trying to run a ElasticSearch docker container on a remote terminal. While trying to run ES, I get that standard max_map_count is too low error and the container stops.

I don't want to change the configuration of the entire terminal because there are many things running on it and they may get affected.

So, is there a way I can specifically change the vm configuration of a docker container while trying to exec it.

Comment: Is it s production cluster or simply a dev one?

Comment: It's a dev cluster but a lot of things are running on it, like hive, spark jobs, many other docker containers and all. So, would it affect all this, the change?

Comment: Do you mind to share your `elasticsearch.yml` configuration file?

Comment: Simply using the image here:

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docker.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're in dev mode, simply starting the image with `-e "discovery.type=single-node"` should do the trick:

```
docker run -p 9200:9200 -p 9300:9300 -e "discovery.type=single-node" docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:6.2.4
```